# Regex is returning only the first word from text

Tags: php, regex

I have problem with my regex expression.
My regex return only first word from text. I want to return all word from this string.

Regex:

```
$test = "Reason: test test test";
$regex = "/Reason: (\w+)+/";
preg_match_all($regex, $test, $reason);
```

Returned code from **var_dump($reason)**:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
        [0]=>
            string(12) "Reason: test"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
        [0]=>
            string(4) "test"
    }
}
```

I want:

```
    array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(12) "Reason: test test test"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(4) "test test test"
    }
}
```

Comment: `.*$` ? ..................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\w` doesn't match whitespaces, only alphanumerical characters. That's why it stops when encountering the first .

If everything is text after the `:`, you may want to use

```
$regex = "/Reason: (.+)/"
```